# RTL Support with Logical CSS Properties

Tags: css, right-to-left, vmware-clarity

I’m in the process of adding RTL to one of the popular open source projects but ran into a problem with the Clarity Design System.

The project uses a lot of ml-x and pl-x classes which messes up when converting to RTL using dir=“rtl” to the html tag.

In Bootstrap, they added support for logical CSS properties, so instead of ml-x you can do ms-x and it will automatically adapt to margin-inline-start instead of margin-left.

Any solution to fix this with VMWare Clairy?

Comment: You could contribute to `Clarity Design System`, converting all spacing properties to logical ones